# Open Source SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, open-source

Is there an open source alternative to SharePoint?

I'd like something that gives the same hierarchical structure and portlet-based design of SharePoint, but is open in source. Web based administration and customization is also a plus.

Comment: There are other facets of SharePoint to consider.  The items you have listed fall into the category of CMS.  SharePoint also offers workflow, wiki, document management, collaboration workspaces, etc.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096392/any-good-open-source-alternative-to-sharepoint?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I depends on what you need.
Is it used as content managment system ? There is plenty open source CMS, as stated before.

Is it used as collaboration tool ?
Then one of the follwing things may do the trick:

- [eGroupWare](http://www.egroupware.org/): Already available on many hosters, project manager, Infolog for Notes, Tasks, ToDos, and more tools.
- [Collanos Workspace](http://www.collanos.com/de/downloads): Java on Mac, Win or Linux, chats, discussions incorporated
- [OpenGoo](http://www.opengoo.org/): PHP, tasks, calendar, contacts, weblinks, internal messages, with editor for text-documents and presentations (!)
- [eyeOS](http://eyeos.org/en/) pushes it one level further. It's like a desktop in your browser, including internal drag and drop etc. It incorporates beforementioned OpenGoo, can be enhanced by a multitude of "programs" to be [downloaded separately](http://eyeos-apps.org/). Sole problem: eyeOS needs full read/write permission on the files, which is often a problem with hosters.

edit: I just found something else and thought it would be worth adding here: [O3Spaces](http://www.o3spaces.org/) (see [german article](http://www.heise.de/open/Groupware-O3spaces-integriert-E-Mail--/news/meldung/121188)) sees itself as alternative to Sharepoint and has just been released in a new version.

Comment: Maybe it is useful (these days) to also look at CMIS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services)

Answer (score 7):

[Disclaimer - I work for Alfresco Open Source Enterprise CMS]

A few days after the original post (on Oct 31st), Alfresco released Alfresco Share, which is an application focused on collaboration.  It has a new UI tailored for Collaboration (built on top of YUI), ability to customize it, and also support for SharePoint Protocol, which means you can connect to it from MS Office (Word, PowerPoint) and use Alfresco as it if were SharePoint - check-in / check-out, versioning, etc.

It's built on the Alfresco ECM Core, which has been around for four years.

Answer (score 3):

You might have a look at [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com), it is often compared as being similar to Sharepoint.

Answer (score 3):

[Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/) is about to release a preconfigured instance of their generic portal server (named Social Office) that is said to be compatible with the sharepoint protocols .

The demo I've seen is impressive. It's available as OpenSource (AGPL) or with commercial support. The underlying portal is MIT-licensed, but it's quite some work to configure it to be that slick.

Sorry to sound like a marketing guy - I'm not. I've seen it demoed on their symposium and just use their portal server.

*Update*: [The Beta has been released](http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/downloads/social_office). As announced earlier, it's AGPL (or, once final, AGPL and commercial)

Comment: There is a commercial version based on Liferay out now, Novell's Teaming product.  So you can get real support for it, which can be a benefit!

Comment: Does that include the sharepoint extensions that make the difference between liferay portal and social office? 
btw: Liferay Inc. soon will have their own commercial version available, of course they already offer support right now. ...so many options...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it would totally fit the bill, but I happen to like [Plone](http://plone.org) on this front.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a non-.NET method, [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/) might fit the bill.

Answer (score 1):

The Java world has a specification for Portals and Portlets (JSR-168 and JSR-286). [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com) is an open source portlet container.

Answer (score 1):

Opengoo is amazing. It is better than sharpoint because it integrates email calendar documents and projects.

Managing projects with Opengoo is much efficient than using MS Project as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a CMS you want, or something just to collaborate.  You may want to look at some sort of wiki solution.

Answer (score 0):

Alfresco is an opensource alternative that supports:

Document management
CMS
Collaboration

http://www.alfresco.com/

Answer (score 0):

At http://groups.diigo.com/search?group_name=collaboration&what=t%3ASharePoint 'Expand All' will show some highlights and annotations on the SharePoint subject.

I'm a Plone fan.

Management is not 100% through the web but it's heading that way, and with grace. The management that's not TTW is exceptionally well supported. Documentation is currently undergoing a major review. Community is *great*.