# SharePoint alternatives?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, web-applications, content-management-system

Hi, I want to develop a site with the features similar to SharePoint but without using any SharePoint services.

Please advise me which are the tools I have to use to achieve this.

The alternative should be free and customizable.

Thanks.

Comment: Uhm... SharePoint is not "just a site". It is a *very complex* content management system. This question cannot be sanely answered as it is now unless, perhaps, you are just interested in a *alternative* system such as [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/).

Comment: @pst - I just want a similar featured site similar to it thats it..

Comment: I have changed the title taking the comment into account. I believe the goal is to find an alternative platform to replace SharePoint, am I correct?

Comment: @pst - Yes an alternative and it should be free and customizable one

Comment: For better answers, put the requires into the original question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any good (open-source) alternative to SharePoint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096392/any-good-open-source-alternative-to-sharepoint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096392/any-good-alternative-for-sharepoint-ofcourse-opensource

And there are some alternatives in this thread as well [Open Source SharePoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247959/open-source-sharepoint)

Comment: WordPress is the king of open source CMS distributions, period.

Comment: @BryanSwan, WordPress is a really neat and lightweight CMS but cannot in any way compete with the enterprise OSS/CMS systems where stuff like continuity, scalability, searchability, processes, automation, security and so on are way more important than pricing and agility. Period.

Comment: That's funny  http://trends.builtwith.com/cms

Comment: @BryanSwan, that statistics only shows the total usage of CMSes, SharePoint is so much more than that. We use SP and such frameworks for collaboration, OSS/BSS applications, enterprise metadata management and so on. As I said, wordpress is great but can only do 1% of what SharePoint does but do that percent very well. Also, the 2008 answer is still correct as many things said in "past days" and while we are at it my answer was written in 2011 in case you missed that.

Answer (score 3):

If your question is: What is an alternative to sharepoint? then one answer would be "alfresco". Although I'm not a fan of Alfresco as a user, it has many features similar to sharepoint: different accessing methods for shared files (WebDAV, HTTP, FTP, SMB), authorization groups and file versioning / history.
Of course it lacks the tight office integration of Sharepoint.

Edit: I'm not a fan of Sharepoint either.

Comment: It is open source and afaik can be used commercially. You should check licensing yourself (or even better make your legal department check it) http://www.alfresco.com/

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you want to with SharePoint. If you are only using 1 functionality you probably have tons of alternatives. (Wordpress, wikipedia, Drupal,..).  All with their own pro's and cons.

If you want the complete package. Collaboration , search, publishing, wiki, blog, office integration, etc... The choices are limited. I'm not a great fan of **DotNetNuke** but it's one possibility. More in the Java camp you find **Alfresco**.